# Populating Field in Form with Images in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm trying to populate a field with images from a model in Django. The idea is that the user will enter the name of their product, then ultimately an API with google images will look that up and populate a field on the next page with a couple images to select.

At this stage, I'm just trying to get a field on the form to show multiple images for the user to select and I'm having a hard time. Here's some of my code, any input is helpful. I know there is a lot out there around this topic and I've looked through a lot but I'm still stuck. My most recent attempt was to create a custom Widget, I'm really open to any solution that will work.

I'm really not a Django/Python wizard so bear with me :) Thank you!

Models.py

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
imageId = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.image)


class Item(models.Model):
itemId = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
itemName = models.CharField(
    "Name",
    max_length=1024,
)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='category'
                             )
itemImage = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='photo',
                              default="",
                              )
itemOwner = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='my_items'
                              )
itemAvaialable = models.BooleanField()
costPerItem = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cost per Item (USD)')
itemDescription = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
itemAddedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
asin = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
```

forms.py

```
class ImageCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ProductImage
    fields = ('image',)

def clean_itemImage(self):
    itemImage = self.cleaned_data['itemImage']
    valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
    extension = itemImage.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    if extension not in valid_extensions:
        raise forms.ValidationError('The given product Image file does not ' \
                                    'match valid image extensions.')
    return itemImage

class ItemCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'itemAddedDate': forms.HiddenInput,
    }
```

Views.py

```
class AddImageView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
model = ProductImage
template_name = 'addImage.html'
fields = ('image',)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.is_valid()
    form.instance.itemOwner = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('RentalApp:my_products')


class AddProductView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Item
template_name = 'addProduct.html'
image = forms.FileField(required=False)
fields = ('itemName',
          'category',
          'itemImage',
          'itemAvaialable',
          'costPerItem',
          'itemDescription')
login_url = '/users/login/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.fields["itemImage"].queryset = ProductImage.objects.all()
    form.is_valid()
    form.instance.itemOwner = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('RentalApp:my_products')
```

Widgets.py

```
class ImageWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        html = Template("""<img src="$link"/>""")
        return mark_safe(html.substitute(link=value))
```

Serializers.py

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('image')


class ProductImageRequirementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('image')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Product_requirement = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,slug_field='text')
    club_image = ProductImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('image')
```

Template for adding a product:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
 <div id="login">
    <h5 class="text-center pt-5">Add Product</h5>
    <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
            <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                <form action="" method="post" id="login-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form|crispy }}
                    <br>
                  <button class="btn btn-success ml-2" type="submit">Save</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'RentalApp:my_products' %}" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">
                    Cancel</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Is there a template you have created that illustrates what you are trying to do or is that what you want help creating?

Comment: @Danoram, I've edited to include a template, it's just a basic form that has a field where I want the user to select from a list of models that are images.